# Running a background thread on a RESTful WebApi request

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Background Workflow:
I have a client (jquery/ajax html page) calling our RESTful WebAPI to get some data (Patient 'encounters' - e.g. admission to a hospital, visit to a clinic, etc.). e.g.

```
public async Task<string> GetEncounters(string patientId)
{
        PatientChart patientChart = await _myService.GetPatientChart(patientId);

        string message = string.Empty;
        if (patientChart.Encounters.Status == PatientChart.StatusNotApplicable)
        {
            message = "List of Encounters is not available. A request has been made to retrieve it.";
            _myService.GetEncounters(patientId); // async method without call to await
        }

        return message;
   }
```

Question
What happens the "GetEncounters" call above where the await keyword is not applied? 
From my understanding, async methods do NOT generate a new thread 
so when the main thread dies, does that mean the call to GetEncounters will abort?
(Behind the scenes, the GetEncounters will fire off a long running process to get data and store it in, e.g. cache, for later retrieval).

If I step through the code, every executes as expected. Likewise, if I add in the await keyword, it also works. (But then I make the caller block)

What's the solution?
i.e. what is the best way to create a background task/thread to execute the code even though the main thread has died?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution depends on how reliable you want the work to be. I.e., if you return the "not available" message, how important is it to you that `GetEncounters` will run?

You should at the very least register the background work with ASP.NET (i.e., `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`). A more reliable solution would save the background work in storage and have an independent backend for processing. I describe [some modern approaches on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).